# multiple kafka consumers with same group id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i'm new to kafka. I have created a kafka consumer with spring boot (spring-kafka dependency). In my app i have used consumerFactory and producerfactory beans for config. So in my application i have created the kafka consumer like below.

```
@RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "3",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
        autoCreateTopics = "false")
  @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myGroupId")
  public void consume(@Payload(required = false) String message) {

       processMessage(message);
  
}
```

My configs are like below

```
@Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.group"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.DEBUG);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }
```

So i want to consume parallelly since i may get more messages. What i found about consuming parallelly topics is that i need to create multiple partitions for a topic and i need to create a consumer for each partition. Let´s say i have 10 partitions for my topic, then i can have 10 consumers in the same consumer group reading one partition each. I understand this behavior. But my concern is how can i create several consumers in my application.

Do i have to write multiple kafka consumer using @KafkaListener with the same functionality ? In that case do i have to write below method X amount of times if i need X amount of same consumers.

```
@RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "3",
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
            autoCreateTopics = "false")
      @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myGroupId")
      public void consume(@Payload(required = false) String message) {
    
           processMessage(message);
      
    }
```

What are the options or configs that i need to achieve parallel consuming with multiple consumers ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` has this option:

```
/**
 * Override the container factory's {@code concurrency} setting for this listener. May
 * be a property placeholder or SpEL expression that evaluates to a {@link Number}, in
 * which case {@link Number#intValue()} is used to obtain the value.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return the concurrency.
 * @since 2.2
 */
String concurrency() default "";
```

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation

Comment: can you please mention the possible values for concurrency? I want to have like 3 concurrent consumers at a given time. So how should i add it ?

Comment: This is not a runtime option. You configure it according the number of your partitions. You can have it higher than partitions number, but only the number of partitions is going to be active concurrent consumers.

Comment: oh okay, i understood. In my topic there are 3 partitions. So i was going to have 3 concurrent consumers. can i just add concurrency like below
`@KafkaListener(id = "myListener", topics = "myTopic",concurrency = "3")`

Comment: Yes, that should be enough. The rule of thumb with Apache Kafka to consume one partition in one thread to preserve ordering. you can consume several partition in one thread, but not opposite.